# location of gpo folder redirection settings

Tags: powershell, redirect, directory, gpo

i'm trying to automate creating gpo's using powershell

I can create the gpo using New-GPO

and if I want to do drive map i can create and edit the following file 
\arc\SYSVOL\server\Policies{GpoId}\User\Preferences\Drives\drives.xml

but I can not find where the folder redirect settings are stored - as far as i can tell there are no specific gpo commands in powershell but the settings must be stored somewhere. any hepl would be grateful

[gpo folder redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzBbK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Redirect settings store at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` . To change this you may use cmdlets:

```
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue
```

Configures a registry preference item under either Computer Configuration or User Configuration in a GPO.

```
Set-GPRegistryValue
```

Configures one or more registry-based policy settings under either Computer Configuration or User Configuration in a GPO.